# I can't pass event's prop to HOC in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, higher-order-components

```
import ParentComponent from "../folder"
<ParentComponent      
dataComponent={() => (
 <ExampleComponent
  {...{prop1, prop2, prop3 }} />
  )}
/>


const ExampleComponent = ({
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3
}) => (
  <>
    <View style={}>
      {!error && (
        <text
          size={5}
        >
          {dummyText}
        </text>
      )}
    </View>
    <Error onTap={tap}/>
  </>
)
```

I have a parent component renderer like this. <Error> component have onTap function which return when user tap a button. And "**ParentComponent**" comes from another file.

```
return <ErrorComponent onTap={reFreshData} />;
```

so i want to trigger reFreshData function in <ParentComponent> 's file but i couldn't handle these flow in React.

Comment: You may want to check the code you pasted, it's not clear what shape your component tree is. You don't return or render parent component.

Comment: Do you want invoke a function from the Parentcomponent in the ExampleComponent ?

Comment: Yes, i have function that i call which is reFetcher let say. when i onTap is triggered, i want to trigger a function which is located in ParentComponent @Noris

Comment: I would pass the callback function (reFetcher) to the child component. In your child component your onTap would look something like this. onTap={(e) => prop.refetcher()}

Comment: actually, i tried that above but i couldn't pass the right way i guess.

Comment: What you want to do is define a lambda function which calls the refresh